# Are there any shortcut keys for responding to meeting requests in MS Office Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am quite proficient with the keyboard and try to only use the mouse when necessary. Given that context I was very familiar with the shortcut keys in MS Outlook 2003 and never needed to use the mouse to use that product. Now my company has recently upgraded to MS Outlook 2010 and I am finding it impossible to operate it without having to use the mouse. In particular replying to meeting requests with the old shortcut keys no longer seems possible.

I have held down the ALT key and sometimes it shows some shortcuts on the ribbon but this seems to be limited to ALT+H which tends to alternate between designating "Accept" and "Tentative" without any keys for the other options. Also as this appears to switch between "Accept" and "Tentative" one can't even use this consistently without first having to check what it means for each particular instance.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Outlook 2010 should still retain the same shortcuts as previous versions, even though they may not display as you type.

Comment: I know that is the behaviour in Excel 2010 but I haven't observed this to be the case in Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just gave pressing ALT+H a try and lo and behold it led to the next level of shortcut keys which then let me select different options for Accept, Tentative and Decline. Although this does mean I have to press a few more keystrokes than in Outlook 2003, this is an acceptable solution for me.

It looks like the ALT+H key was actually for selecting the ribbon tab to move to and then likewise for the next level of buttons etc... . When I had noticed previously that the ALT+H appeared to refer to different buttons, this must have been due to unfortunate button placement which made it look like it was associated with a different button.

Answer (score 11):

1. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (to open the calendar request)
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (home menu), then <kbd>C</kbd> (Accept the request), then <kbd>S</kbd> (send the response now)

Comment: Is there an equivalent for this on macOS?

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you have the context menu key on your keyboard, is to press it whilst highlighting an email, press down three times, then enter, then enter again to get past the final menu.