# Keybinding to remove canceled meeting from calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

When a meeting is cancelled, I receive an email with a "Remove from Calendar" button.

[image]

Is there any way to remove the meeting from the calendar using the keyboard only?

Comment: Try the following  "Select  “Ctrl + A”. Press “Delete” key button to remove them"    See if that works. I find it much faster and more productive with a mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/591303/123993) to another question helped me find the way. You have to first open the email in its own window with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then Navigate to the ribbon with <kbd>Alt+H</kbd>, then Remove From Calendar with <kbd>E</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with John, removing items from your calendar using "Delete" key should be OK. And if you would like to remove batch of Outlook calendar items, the Outlook archive feature can also help.

Fore more information: [Remove items from your calendar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/remove-items-from-your-calendar-359f0a1a-15f1-4751-a8be-579cbb845926).

[image]

Comment: I don't want to delete all items from my calendar. I only want to delete the cancelled ones.

Comment: You can use Outlook view setting to filter those Canceled calendar items. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10-mso_365hp/outlook-meeting-has-been-canceled-how-to-hide/76ee7207-9939-4ebc-8343-5c0045ceaed8