# How can I accept several meeting invitations at once in Microsoft Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How can I accept several meeting invitations at once in Microsoft Outlook 2013?

Comment: Apparently you can enable one-click accept as a toggle which might help: https://superuser.com/questions/205604/single-click-to-accept-meeting-invite-in-outlook-2010

Comment: Is there a third-party or VBA that would do it?  I'm using the last stand-alone Outlook, 2019, which behaves the same as 13 and 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way built into the Outlook 2013 standard interface to accept multiple discrete invitations simultaneously.

There is **Automatic Accept or Decline**, found in **File > Options > Calendar** which will accept every invitation that does not conflict with an existing calendar event.

There are **Macros** which could be written to accomplish this in some form.

And there is a toggle that activates **Send Response Now** mode that is normally hidden from the UI but that can be made visible and available using this answer here: [Single click to accept meeting invite in Outlook 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/205604/single-click-to-accept-meeting-invite-in-outlook-2010)

Note, that answer is specifically for Office 2010. In Office 2016 the name has been changed or is no longer a valid command. I do not have Office 2013 handy to see if it it available there.